# Missing authorization header and hook return undefined while searching for data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux, rtk-query

Currently I'm working with a chat application which is based on json-server now the problem is while I'm requesting for conversations with like search (http://localhost:9000/conversations?participants_like=tushin@gmail.com&_sort=timestamp&_order=desc&_page=1&_limit=5) it showing 200 response but data won't shown up! while I check the json server it showing "missing authorization header"

Here is my conversation api

```
import { apiSlice } from "../api/apiSlice";

export const conversationsApi = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        //endpoints here
        getConversations: builder.query({
            query: (email) => `/conversations?participants_like=${email}&_sort=timestamp&_order=desc&_page=1&_limit=5`, 
        })
        
    })
})

export const {useGetConversationsQuery } = conversationsApi;
```

here is my converation slice

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
const initialState = {}

const conversationsSlice = createSlice({
    name: "conversations",
    initialState,
    reducers: {}
})

// export const { } = conversationsSlice.actions;
export default conversationsSlice.reducer;
```

here is my apiSlice

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: "api", 
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
        prepareHeaders: async (headers, { getState, endpoint }) => {
            const token = getState()?.auth?.accessToken;
            if (token) {
                headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
            }
            console.log(headers)
            return headers;
        }
    }), 
    tagTypes: [],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        
    })
})
```

Comment: I think there's "await" missing in the prepareHeaders function. Since it's async, there should be an await somewhere (either for "getState" or for "headers.set"

Comment: I tried but its now working any another solution ?

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/2107